# Directly send multiple files after Url called

Tags: php, html

I'm wondering how some sites like Facebook can directly send their `.js` and `.css` files when you go on the website. When you go on "normal" sites then you get for example the `index.html` or `index.php` back and then later the needed .js and .css files.

When a user calls my site example.com how do i direcly send them some .css and .js and maybe even some .jpg files like facebook does?

Here are 2 examples of facebook and a site which sends data like me at the moment:

[image: Facebook sends data directly]

[image: Other site first loads index.php, sends it to client and later .css and .js files]

I have a php-backend when when somebody goes on my side example.com (so my index.php is called) I would like to directly send some sources too. Is that possible and if yes how does Facebook or some other pages do it?

Comment: These are ajax call or js/css files.when you run your site, your css/js/image files will show same as facebook. No need to change any thing.Or no special coding is required

Comment: Yes but my site needs 100-200ms to send back my echo from index.php call and then the browser interprets it and then asks for .js and .css files needed and so on (like on picture 2). How does facebook directly send the things?

Comment: Add the “protocol” column in network panel ... and you’ll see that Facebook uses `h2`, meaning HTTP/2. And that includes _server push_ for assets such as stylesheets, scripts etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, the h2 push was the thing i was looking for! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by CBroe, the HTTP/2 push is the key! :-)